# Unauthorized error when trying to get Nest Access Token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, nest-api

Everything was working fine until a couple days ago, I started getting an Unauthorized error when trying to get a Nest Access Token.  I've double checked and the client ID and client secret code are all correct.  Any ideas on what could be causing it?

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?");
var token = await request.GetValueFromRequest<NestToken>(string.Format(
    "client_id={0}&code={1}&client_secret={2}&grant_type=authorization_code",
                CLIENTID,
                code.Value,
                CLIENTSECRET));

public async static Task<T> GetValueFromRequest<T>(this HttpWebRequest request, string postData = null)
{
    T returnValue = default(T);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData))
    {
        byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var postStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            await postStream.WriteAsync(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        request.Method = "GET";
    }

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

    if (response != null)
    {
        using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream))
            {
                var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

                using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
                {
                    return (T)serializer.ReadObject(tempStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rohit,

I've been working on a .NET wrapper around the Nest REST API. I don't see too many folks using .NET so I thought I would share my work:

http://github.com/mitchdenny/birdhouse/

I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json package for my JSON serialization/deserialization and it seems to have been working fine, although in this case it sounds like it was a glitch on the Nest side.

Comment: Pretty cool, didn't realize this existed.  I'll be sure to give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be because of a fault on Nest's end which was later fixed.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't provide an answer I can confirm the same thing is happening to my iOS app in the same timeframe.

Taking my url and post values works fine using postman in chrome. Alamofire is throwing up error 401, as is native swift test code like yours.

Have Nest perhaps changed their https negotiation?

Comment: I'm also getting this with my OS X app.

Comment: So far I've been unable to find records of changes on the Nest side, but it does look as though they've changed something.I'm working on the basis that they've implemented a new architecture to support their move to lower quotes, etc.

Comment: I can also confirm that it works fine via a regular request (using Paw.app) - however it is not using `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: OK so; If you pass the parameters in the URL instead of adding them to the body, the request goes through just fine.

Comment: Good to know, I'll give it a try with my alamofire setup.

Comment: Rdougan, you called it. Works fine when submitting via a url. I do wonder why the sudden change on the Nest server side. At least we have a workaround.

Comment: As of today, it seems to be working fine for me again without any changes.

Comment: Great news Rohit. I personally believe Nest should explain what has happened. This affected app sales and reputation as it's seen as an app fault, not a service provider issue.

Comment: Nest have confirmed a fault in their end "which is now fixed" but no detail and the root cause.